# Show current Activity in background when launching AlertDialog from BroadcastRecevier

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I have a translucent AlertDialog set to show if the user receives a text message. It is being started from a Broadcast Receiver.

The user only gets this "emergency" type of message, only if the sender sets it as such a message *and* the user enables this type of interruption.

I have a slight problem because if my application is running, my background is what my application last left off at. The only way I get the background to show what the user is "currenty doing" is by completely closing my app.

Has anyone run into a similar issue using AlertDialogs with a translucent background?

here is how I start my activity;

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, LayoutStartActivity.class);
i.putExtras(intent);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

and here is a stripped down version of my alert dialog

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(holder);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the task affinity in the AndroidManifest.xml so that it runs as a unique process on the recents stack.

Example

```
<activity android:name=".LayoutStartActivity"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.Light"
                    android:taskAffinity="com.example.standAlone">
```

Comment: I had a transparent theme, but that taskAffinity tag was greatly helpful. You are the best ! Thanks :)